# Asp.net Core 6: Missing reference from Package ZXing.Net.Maui Barcode Scanner

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, maui

Can somebody help me with a problem I can't seem to resolve?
I'm trying to set up a barcode scanner in MAUI via the package ZXing.Net.Maui that I found in a tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ostgj2xB_ok&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

I get the following messages that VS2022 is not able to recognize the package ZXing.Net.Maui even though I have the package installed.

[image]

These are the errors that VS 2022

[image]

I have imported the ZXing package but VS doesn't seem to give me any red lines from errors

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find ZXing.Net.Maui package but a different one that seems to relate to the other package. I installed the 1.0.4 since the 1.0.5 version is deprecated.

Can someone help me? I need to use this package

Comment: Please don’t post code or errors as images.  And it would be very helpful to include a link to the specific nuget package you are using

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Maui/0.3.0-preview.1

Answer (score 5):

Install package `ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls`

Then add namesapce `using ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls`;

source -> https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui/issues/90